# Vue 3: Why is my composable not reactive?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuejs3

I want to use 1 composable from within another. My first composable is basically a super lightweight version of Vuex:

```
import {
  reactive,
  readonly,
} from 'vue';

const state = reactive({
  settings: {
    loading: true,
  },
  cart: {
    loading: true,
    items: [],
  },
});

export default {
  state: readonly(state),
};
```

When I try to use this in another composable, the `cart` is not being reactive.

In my other composable I have:

```
import store from '@/store';
watch(store.state.cart, () => {
  console.log('test');
});
```

And it doesn't seem to react to anything. When I try calling `.value` on it, its undefined, as if it's not a proxy.

I also tried using `inject('store')` and that seems to do the same thing.

I want to watch when any part of the cart changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is long and involved, but it basically boils down to:

1. Part of it is a javascript problem, in that the way I was updating `cart` was by replacing the entire key of the object with an API call, so the inner cart key was getting updated with a different reference. You can visualize the problem [here](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=const%20store%20%3D%20%7B%20state%3A%20%7Bcart%3A%20%7Btotal%3A%20100,%20items%3A%201%7D%7D%20%7D%3B%0Aconst%20cart%20%3D%20store.state.cart%3B%0Astore.state.cart.total%20%2B%3D%201%0Astore.state.cart%20%3D%20%7Btotal%3A%20200,%20items%3A%202%7D%3B&cumulative=false&curInstr=4&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)
2. I had to use `toRef` which is subtly different from `ref`, in that it is specifically for extracting reactive keys out of a reactive object. I thought this only applied to destructuring but it also applies to simply saying `const cart = store.state.cart`, as when I updated the cart this `cart` variable would point to the old reference. `toRef` solves this by writing: `const cart = toRef(store.state, 'cart')`

Comment: Thanks to the idea. This is very helpful for the case when defineProps() properties are passed to composables. Sometimes the provided data from props change but composables are not recalculated.