# Why is this composable not reactive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-composition-api

I have this composable in my app:

```js
// src/composition-api/usePermissions.js
import { ref, readonly } from 'vue'
import { fetchData } from 'src/utils/functions/APIFunctions'

export function usePermissions() {
  const permissions = ref([])
  const name = ref('')

  const fetchCurrentUser = () => {
    fetchData('users/me').then(res => {
      name.value = `${res.first_name} ${res.last_name}`
      permissions.value = res.roles
    })
  }

  return {
    name: readonly(name),
    permissions: readonly(permissions),
    fetchCurrentUser,
  }
}
```

`FetchCurrentUser` is called in the main layout component.

```html
<template>
  <!-- src/layouts/MainLayout.vue -->
  <q-layout view="lHh Lpr lFf">
    <!-- Redacted for brevity -->
  </q-layout>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import EssentialLink from "src/components/EssentialLink.vue";
import { usePermissions } from "src/composition-api/usePermissions";

const { fetchCurrentUser } = usePermissions();

/* redacted for brevity */

onMounted(() => {
  fetchCurrentUser();
});
</script>
```

And the state is used in other components, such as this one.

```html
<template>
 <!-- src/components/loggedUserLabel.vue -->
  <div>{{ name }}</div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { usePermissions } from "src/composition-api/usePermissions.js";

const { name } = usePermissions();
</script>
```

The `fetchCurrentUser()` function is used when starting the app or when a new user logs in. I want to use this composable in other components to restrict access to some parts of the app depending on user permissions, and to display the username. However, the `name` and `permissions` properties are not reacting to changes. What could be wrong here?

If it matters, I'm using Quasar. I could use Pinia for this but I only need this kind of store-like shared state here, so it seems like overkill to add another library.

At Estus Flask's request, I have created a [MCVE](https://codesandbox.io/s/composable-mcve-thevzf?file=/src/layouts/MainLayout.vue) - and the same problem keeps happening. Note how in `src/layouts/MainLayout.vue` the API call is made, but the message in `src/components/PokemonLabel.vue` does not update, despite receiving a valid response from the Pokeapi.

I have found [a similar answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869080/vue-3-why-is-my-composable-not-reactive) but it is about a different situation.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Nothing is wrong. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem

Comment: My bad! I have edited the original question with a link to a Codesandbox.

Comment: Please, provide the relevant code in the question, i.e. how usePermissions is used, this way it will make sense for other readers without navigating to external links which can become unavailable

Comment: The state of `fetchCurrentUser` isn't shared between comps where you use it, this is by design. You call fetch in one place and use the state in another, it won't work like that. If you need a state that is shared between comps, use global store. This isn't what a composable like this one is for. Can't recommend what's the best way to do this in Quasar yourself, as global stores need to be treated differently rather than in pure Vue. Likely use `provide` for `reactive` object in  App comp and `inject` in `use..` fn. Any way, that's what pinia is for. You'll have to reinvent the wheel otherwise

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll probably end up using Pinia, now that I know this about how composables work. For the sake of completeness, I have added the relevant code to my question, so future users can understand the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` and `fetchCurrentUser` are supposed to be used in the same component. The state of fetchCurrentUser isn't shared between components, this is by design.

In order to make the state global, it should be created once per component hierarchy, e.g.:

```js
const name = ref('')

export function usePermissions() {
  const fetchCurrentUser = ...

  return {
    name: readonly(name),
    fetchCurrentUser,
  }
}
```

This won't work correctly for SSR application like Quasar because there are multiple application instances for different users, but the state is created once and shared between them. In this case the state likely should be created for a hierarchy of components, e.g.:

```js
export function setupPermissions() {
  const name = ref('')
  const fetchCurrentUser = ...


  provide('permissionsStore', {
    name: readonly(name),
    fetchCurrentUser,
  })
}

export function usePermissions() {
  return inject('permissionsStore');
}
```

Where `usePermissions` is used in child component. And `setupPermissions` is used in root component, or can be rewritten as a plugin.